# Find two integers with Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

Find **two** intergers having remainders 3, 11, 15 when divided by 10, 13, 17, respectively.

I found one is $1103$. But I'm confused about the other one.

Comment: How about $1103+10\cdot 13\cdot 17$?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. But why that number? Why is it correct when we add that?

Comment: Because $$a+b\pmod{n} = (a\pmod{n}+b\pmod{n})\pmod{n}$$ In other words, adding $10k_1 \pmod{10}$ is the same as adding $0\pmod{10}$. Adding $13k_2\pmod{13}$ is the same as adding $0\pmod{13}$. And finally, adding $17k_3\pmod{17}$ is the same as adding $0\pmod{17}$. So, I needed to add a number that was a multiple of all three of the divisors (10, 13, and 17). So, I multiplied them together. In fact, it works for $1103+10\cdot 13\cdot 17k$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: Better way to show it: $$\dfrac{1103+a}{10} = \dfrac{1103}{10}+\dfrac{a}{10}$$ You already know that $$\dfrac{1103}{10}$$ has remainder 3. So, if we don't want to change the remainder, we must have $10$ divides $a$. Similarly for $13$ and $17$.

Answer (score 1):

You want a number $1103+a$ such that

$$\dfrac{1103+a}{10} = \dfrac{1103}{10}+\dfrac{a}{10}$$

has remainder 3,

$$\dfrac{1103+a}{13} = \dfrac{1103}{13}+\dfrac{a}{13}$$

has remainder 11, and

$$\dfrac{1103+a}{17} = \dfrac{1103}{17}+\dfrac{a}{17}$$

has remainder 15.

Since you know the remainders of $\dfrac{1103}{10}, \dfrac{1103}{13}, \dfrac{1103}{17}$ already match the remainders you desire, it must be that $10$ divides $a$, $13$ divides $a$, and $17$ divides $a$. The least common multiple of those divisors is $10\cdot 13\cdot 17$. So, the set of numbers with the remainders you are looking for would be:

$$1103+10\cdot 13\cdot 17k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Choose any two.